# Two autocomplete fields via Google API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api

I have this two fields with `id="Pickup Location"` and `id="Drop Location"`. I want to auto-complete the fields with names of Indian cities.

```
<input type="text" value="" name="form[Pickup Location]" id="Pickup Location" onfocus="geolocate()" class="rsform-input-box">

<input type="text" value="" name="form[Drop Location]" id="Drop Location" onfocus="geolocate()" class="rsform-input-box">
```

And I have this Google API code that auto completes and it works perfectly. However, the JS is written for the input field to work with `id="autocomplete"` only.

So now, how do I re-write the JS so that it accepts both `Pick Location` and `Drop Location`?

PS: I don't need the `id=autocomplete` field and will be discarding it.

```
<input id="autocomplete" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text">

<script>
      // This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
      // of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

      // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
      // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
      // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

      var placeSearch, autocomplete;
      var componentForm = {
        street_number: 'short_name',
        route: 'long_name',
        locality: 'long_name',
        administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
        country: 'long_name',
        postal_code: 'short_name'
      };

      function initAutocomplete() {
        // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
        // location types.
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
            {types: ['geocode']});

        // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
        // fields in the form.
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
      }

      function fillInAddress() {
        // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        for (var component in componentForm) {
          document.getElementById(component).value = '';
          document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
        }

        // Get each component of the address from the place details
        // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
        for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
          var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
          if (componentForm[addressType]) {
            var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
            document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
          }
        }
      }

      // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
      // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
      function geolocate() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var geolocation = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
            var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
              center: geolocation,
              radius: position.coords.accuracy
            });
            autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
          });
        }
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyADbpfJGWwRh5um_gd2gNySgrI5FAy2RZk&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I can't code in JS and so the best I could do is change the id from `Pickup Location` to `autocomplete`.

Comment: ouch... ok... do you have a fiddle or a public webpage where you have this code running?

Comment: http://liveweave.com/Rns9r0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code requires quite a few changes, so I'll keep it basic.

The `fillInAddress()` function needs html elements to store values for both locations. Since those elements are not present I've removed that code.

The `geolocate()` function looks to be used only for plotting on a map, which is not present in your code, so I removed it.

So the following is for autocomplete only. You still need to figure out how to return only Indian cities via google maps API.

```js
var placeSearch, pickupLocation, dropLocation;

function initAutocomplete() {
    // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
    // location types.
    pickupLocation = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */
    (document.getElementById('Pickup_Location')), {
      types: ['geocode']
    });

    dropLocation = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */
    (document.getElementById('Drop_Location')), {
      types: ['geocode']
    });
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" name="form[Pickup Location]" id="Pickup_Location" placeholder="Pickup Location" class="rsform-input-box">

<input type="text" value="" name="form[Drop Location]" id="Drop_Location" placeholder="Drop Location" class="rsform-input-box">

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyADbpfJGWwRh5um_gd2gNySgrI5FAy2RZk&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code should work for you according to your requirement! Make sure the form filling procedure you've written works fine

```js
function initAutocomplete() {
  var myFirstEle = document.getElementById('firstEle'),
    mySecondEle = document.getElementById('secondEle');
  generateAutoComplete(myFirstEle);
  generateAutoComplete(mySecondEle);

}

function generateAutoComplete(ele) {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
  // location types.
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */
    ele, {
      types: ['geocode']
    });

  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
  // fields in the form.
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress.bind(autocomplete));

}

 function fillInAddress(autocomplete) {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    for (var component in componentForm) {
      document.getElementById(component).value = '';
      document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }

    // Get each component of the address from the place details
    // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
      var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
      if (componentForm[addressType]) {
        var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
        document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this is gonna work! There's no demo either.